# JTable header with custom Default Renderer does not scroll inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable inside a JScrollPane, inside a JTabbedPane. The table header scrolls fine until I set a custom default renderer for it that dynamically changes the width and height of the header cells, i.e.:

```
table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new MyHeaderRenderer());
```

... where MyHeaderRenderer extends a JLabel and its getTableCellRendererComponent() method sets the preferred size like this:

```
table.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

After settings the custom renderer the table body continues scrolling correctly, but the header stays fixed to the upper left corner of the JScrollPane. I believe the renderer is repainting the header continuously in that position.

How could I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't set the preferred size. Swing components should determine there own preferred size and scrolling only works when the preferred size is calculated dynamically.

Comment: "table.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize" - well, that's not going to end well

Comment: Don't setPrefferedSize() override getPreferredSize() if you must. Why do you do this anyways?

Comment: Yes, you were right. It can't be done by using setPreferredSize(). I got it working with a pretty dumb change. I've posted an answer. Thanks to you all :-)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had lots of columns with long header texts, so I created a header renderer to set the height and width of the header cells according to the length of the cell text.

As it turns out, you can't resize the header cells by setting the preferred size of the table header itself or you'll end up with a header always fixed to the upper left corner of the table.

Regarding this matter, I found no solution.
I tried setting preferredSize outside the renderer: it didn't work, which means the problem is not the continuous rendering.
I tried using a JTextArea instead of a JLabel: it made no difference.
I tried overriding the JTable doLayout() method: it didn't work.

I fixed the issue by removing:

```
table.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

... and adding these code lines to the getTableCellRendererComponent() method:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width); //sets the width
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height)); //sets the height of the JLabel returned by the renderer
```

This was the best I could think of. If anyone finds a better solution, please share it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found a workaround.
JTable header is a separate component, that stored inside parent JScrollPane ColumnHeader. So, instead of overriding header preferred size we can set preferred size of JScrollPane ColumnHeader.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
scrollPane.getColumnHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, height));
```

Fortunately, JScrollPane ignores column header width, so you can safely set zero here.